# Public Methods Inaccessible in Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, public-method

i have the problem of not being able to call my own methods in object elements of an array

Here is the code for the part of the code with the array:

```
public class CardRules {
    private Object cardArray[];

public CardRules(Object cardArrayCopy[]){

    cardArray = cardArrayCopy;
    multiples();
}
public void multiples(){
for(Object ArrayElement: cardArray){
    System.out.println(ArrayElement);
}
}
}
```

And for the Card Object:

```
public class Card {
    private int rank;
    private int suit;
    private String Stringrank[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    private String Stringsuit[] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    public static int CardNo = 0;

public Card(int cardDetails[]){
    rank = cardDetails[1];
    suit = cardDetails[0];
    CardNo++;
}
public String getCard(){
    return ("Card: " + Stringrank[rank] + " Of " + Stringsuit[suit]);

}
   public int getRank(){
       return rank;
   }
   public int getSuit(){
       return suit;
   }
```

}

The output for this part of the program is  the hash codes, 
Card@9304b1
Card@190d11
Card@a90653
Card@de6ced
Card@c17164

i would like to put something like or similar

```
System.out.println(ArrayElement.getRank());
```

does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

btw the array is copied from an ArrayList in another class using the premade .toArray() method

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can't know those objects are cards, since you declare them as `Object`s in the array. if you are sure that they will be cards, declare the array as `Card` (`private Card cardArray[];`) or cast them `((Card)ArrayElement).getRank()`.

If you want to check one more time, use `ArrayElement instanceof Card` to validate that this is a real `Card` instance before casting.

Comment: If he has access to the other class where the `ArrayList` is converted to an array, he can also make it return an array of the `Card` type by passing the array to the `toArray` method. That way he could avoid the explicit casting on individual array elements. e.g. `Card[] cardArray = (Card[]) list.toArray(new Card[array.size()])`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` invokes `Object.toString()`, So overwrite the `toString()` method of class Card. (btw: it's better to make the `Stringrank` and `Stringsuit` both static):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Card [rank= %s, suit= %s]", 
           Stringrank[rank], Stringsuit[suit]);
}
```

Comment: Even better to declare them as enums. It's unlikely card ranks and suits will change anytime soon.